# Failed opening required on localhost after switching to mac

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

So long story short, I finally made the switch from Windows to Mac. I installed XAMPP on my new computer and have everything working. Now I am transferring local WP installs from my old computer and found this error...

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid//admin/includes/update.class.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/essential-grid.php
>   on line 133

2 things. First, this isn't a problem with the plugin files themselves because they work fine on the local and live sites. Second, I highlighted where I think the error is here "essential-grid//admin", but I'm not really sure what is causing it. Is there something I need to change in my new XAMPP config?

I'm guessing it's probably a simple configuration that I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it actually isn't forward slashes. I am reproducing the problem with other files and the error message is reporting the exact directories where the files seem to be.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the files got corrupted during the file transfer so this wasn't a problem with XAMPP. Everything worked out.